# How to create an image slideshow from images in a mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a mysqli database and form which allows me to store an id, name and photo. The path of the photo is set to an "images" folder on the server. I have a query which can

> SELECT * FROM images WHERE name = $pagetitle.

This works absolutely fine, outside of the javascript slideshow. When i put a php command in the javascript where it is looking for which images to display, the js only shows 1 image, and not ALL images.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

The section of the code in question is below...

### index.php

```html
            <!-- Image Slide Show Start -->
  <div style="display: flex; justify-content: center;">
  <img align="middle" src="" name="slide" border=0 width=300 height=375>
    
<script>

<?php 
require('dbconnect.php');
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE name= '$pagetitle'");
$image = mysql_fetch_array( $data );



?>
//configure the paths of the images, plus corresponding target links
slideshowimages("<?php echo "/images/".$image['photo'] . ""?>")

//configure the speed of the slideshow, in miliseconds
var slideshowspeed=2000

var whichlink=0
var whichimage=0
function slideit(){
if (!document.images)
return
document.images.slide.src=slideimages[whichimage].src
whichlink=whichimage
if (whichimage<slideimages.length-1)
whichimage++
else
whichimage=0
setTimeout("slideit()",slideshowspeed)
}
slideit()


</script> </div><br><br>
      <!-- Image Slide Show End -->
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Replace $vbCrLf with "<br>". Too many errors.

Comment: Replacing $vbCrLf has added a syntax error,  unexpected '<'

Comment: you're using `mysqli_` code in one file, then `mysql_` in the other, *why?* We don't even know which API you're using to connect with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE name= '$pagetitle'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$directory = '';
while( $image = $result->fetch_assoc() )
    $directory .= ($directory != '' ? "," : '') . ('"/images/'.$image["photo"] . '"');



// Check if it was successfull
    if($directory != '') {

    // if there are images for this page, run the javascript
    ?><script>


    //configure the paths of the images, plus corresponding target links            
    slideshowimages(<?php print $directory ?>)
```

Answer (score 2):

your update query have syntax errors, use `,` between fields, also you must contain strings in 2 `'` :

```
$query = "UPDATE page_content SET PageTitle='$pageTitle',
PageContent='$PageContent', PageContent2='$PageContent2' WHERE PageId='$PageId'";
```

Comment: I have updated the file with your correction, however it still fails. I am not getting any errors. Just getting "Failed to update"

Answer (score 1):

You have missed `,` between fields and `''` around variables in your query.

```
$sql = "UPDATE page_content SET PageTitle='$pageTitle', 
       PageContent='$PageContent', PageContent2='$PageContent2' 
       WHERE PageId='$PageId'";

// check query executed successfully or get error
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

OR

```
$result = mysqli_query($sql) or trigger_error("Query Failed! SQL: $sql - Error: ".mysqli_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but still failing. I have just had a thought, could it be the the variable for the dropdown is incorrect. as currently the field shows <?php echo $DropDownList; ?>  and $DropDownList .= "<option value='$heading'>$heading</option> ".$vbCrLf; $heading = $row[0];

Comment: @Liam: Post your dropdown code in question. I need to check $vbCrLf and $row variables

Comment: Update_page.php has been added to question.